# HERE MAPS returns blank tiles after reloading page in Vue + Veutify

Tags: here-api, heremaps

**Problem**
Developed a component vue and included all necessary steps and manage to have it working with correct apikey configuration. Map component in page loads correctly for the 1st time. Upon reloading, HERE api returns blank tiles and this continues until code changes made to either mounted or created vue lifecycle hooks.

**Observation of Network Activities**
Found 2 cases of which HERE maps returns a normal tile or a blank tile

**Normal Tile:**
Upon 1st load or reload after code changes made to mounted hook

Request URL made by HERE api for a single tile
https://4.aerial.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/09e0643c22/hybrid.day/17/**103309**/**65001**/512/jpg?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.16.2&apikey=blablabla

**Blank Tile:**
Upon consecutive page reloads

Request URL made by HERE api for single tile
https://1.aerial.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/09e0643c22/hybrid.day/17/**65536**/**65535**/512/jpg?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.16.2&apikey=blablabla


From observation, only when the values (highlighted in bold) changes that made the map returns either blank or normal tiles. I'm assuming those values are associated with the longitude and latitude of the map requested or maybe the size of the tile. Not sure.

The problem consistently occurs upon page reloading even when the live reloading was stopped and restarted. It will only show normal tiles when code changes were made in mounted lifecycle hook during live reload.

Comment: Are you getting the same response with 'normal.day'. can you try change hybrid day to some other mode and confirm.

Comment: let mapLayer = mapTileService.createTileLayer(
      'maptile',
      'normal.day',
      tileSize,
      'png8',
      { lg: 'VIE', ppi: ppi }
    );

Comment: I've changed to normal day using the code below  
  
this.map = new H.Map(this.$refs.map,
      this.defaultLayers.raster.normal.map,
      {
        zoom: 18,
        center: coords
      }
    )
  
It behaves the same. On the consecutive page reloads, it loads a blank tile

Comment: Ok. I don't know what happened, but I guess this problem is still related to map size as well. When I fixed the size of the div using fixed width and length. It can show the normal tiles. I've also changed the map root tag of the component to use only div and not v-container.